# Combine multiple Excel workbooks into a single workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am a novice at Visual Basic. I can use either Excel 2010 or Excel 2013 for this task.

I have dozens of workbooks with data on the first worksheet of each. For example One.xlsx, Two.xlsx, Three.xlsx, Four.xlsx each contain information on their respective Sheet1.

I need the information on Sheet1 from each workbook to be combined into a single workbook with sheets that are named from the file name of the original workbook. So for example combined.xlsx would have 4 sheets named One, Two, Three, Four. In every case all information on the underlying worksheets should be copied and combined in the new Workbook as shown below.

- The Format I need

[image]

I found this Macro / Add-In online that gets me close to what I need using the open files add in choice.

http://www.excelbee.com/merge-excel-sheets-2010-2007-2013#close

The Open Files Add-In successfully allows me to aggregate the various Workbook's worksheets into a single workbook. However the tabs are not named from the name of the original file.

- Correct aggregation of sheets, but incorrect worksheet names.

[image]

For now all the underlying Workbooks will be in the same folder. The ability to browse and select the files would be nice if this ever changes but if that is too difficult, just indicating the directory path in the Visual Basic code would work. As far as the resultant combined output probably ought to be a new workbook, the filename of the new workbook isn't that important. It could be called combined.xlsx for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following accomplishes the task.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer
Dim WrdArray() As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "c:\test\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
        WrdArray() = Split(fileName, ".")
        For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
        Workbooks(fileName).ActiveSheet.Name = WrdArray(0)
            total = Workbooks("import-sheets.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
            Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy after:=Workbooks("import-sheets.xlsm").Worksheets(total)

            GoTo exitFor:

        Next sheet

exitFor:
    Workbooks(fileName).Close
    fileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: is `import-sheets.xlsm` the file that I'm running the macro ?

Comment: Could you add some comments into it ?

Comment: Not necessary anymore, thank you for your post. help me a lot. I did some improvements, should I share it ? https://gist.github.com/wviana/31d8dac7718b952e1ccf43eb3ee062be I settled some vars, to facilitate the operation, removing the need to call `Workbooks(fileName)` every time. Sorry by the comments in Portuguese.

Comment: There is only one problem that I'm getting, about the colours from the sheets it's copping. In source it has different colours from destiny workbook.

Comment: the xlsm-File with the code should named import-sheets.xlsm

Answer (score 1):

In Excel press `Alt+F11`, this will open the Excel VBA editor.

Article http://www.excel-spreadsheet.com/vba/debugging.htm explains some basics how to use it.

In `Module1` there are 2 short subroutines `opensheets` and `merge` containing ~50 lines of code.

Use `F1` with cursor within words you don't understand, to learn what it means.

Once you understand what the code does, you can tailor it to your needs.

Comment: I was hoping for some similar code to achieve my goal rather than starting from scratch

Comment: @JayC the code is there, right in the macro, changing it to create new workbook or renaming sheets are simple one-liners. But Stack Overflow is **not code writing service**. You have to show some effort, write some code, show it and Stack Overflow can help you diagnose and overcome concrete coding problems. I suggest that you start solving your task by trying to understand those ~50 lines of code in the Merge-Macro.xlsm and perhaps spawn some new more concrete coding questions. So far you are doing quite well

Comment: Thanks, I agree and understand some effort and a template for the problem is needed. Unfortunately the linked macro is not editable so I couldn't use it to guide me. In this case a coworker was able to get me started and I further modified it to meet my needs.

Comment: @JayC it is great that you have found your way. Posting a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) may be useful for future readers. BTW: **source code** of the macros `opensheets` and `merge` in the `Merge-Macro.xlsm` **is available**, you can investigate it using the method in my answer and it is how I've found out that we are talking about ~50 lines of code. I saw the code. You could see it as well