# Merging two spreadsheets using a script and creating HTML language

Tags: excel

I have to merge this two stylesheet - http://www.j-e.com/Demo_Database.xlsx

The first one "DB" is a database of products, is a music shop.
As you can see I have four columns: the id of the product, the title, the price, and the tracklist.
Title and price are OK, but the column of the tracklist for now is empty.

The second one "TRACKS" is where my tracks are. Tree columns, the first one is the id of the produt who refer, the second column is the number of the track, and the third column is the title.

I need to merge all the tracks on different lines for each product from "TRACKS" in a single cell of the tracklist in "DB"

The real BESTBESTBEST is to have a structure like this in the cell tracklist of "DB" :

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>TITLE_1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2.</td>
        <td>TITLE_2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3.</td>
        <td>TITLE_3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I think you need to write the data from 2 different excel files into 1 excel file. If I am right, why don't you try to read the data from 2 excel files and store it in vb variables and create another excel file and write the data into it as you want. Otherwise, some links here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/3-ways-merge-de-duplicate-excel-files-martin-judd, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455076/combine-multiple-excel-workbooks-into-a-single-workbook, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837974%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks Mate for the hint! i'll give it a read!

Answer (score 0):

the question is 
solved here:

http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?54574-Merging-two-spreadsheets-using-a-script-and-creating-html-language

Thanks