# Copy data from multiple workbooks in a folder into one workbook paste special only value

Tags: excel, consolidation, vba

I want to Copy all sheets of multiple workbooks within a folder into another single workbook. I found below code but do not know how to paste special only values to avoid unnecessary formatting.

```
Sub GetSheets()

Path = "C:\Users\mechee69\Download\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets    
        Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)    
    Next Sheet  
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()
Loop 

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine multiple Excel workbooks into a single workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455076/combine-multiple-excel-workbooks-into-a-single-workbook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, it will `PasteSpecial` only the `Values`, if you want you can extend to copy also the `Formats`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetSheets()

Dim Path As String, Filename As String
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet, ShtDest As Worksheet

Path = "C:\Users\mechee69\Download\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls*")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Do While Filename <> ""
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
    For Each Sht In WB.Sheets
        Set ShtDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(1))
        Sht.Cells.Copy
        ShtDest.Name = Sht.Name '<-- might raise an error in case there are 2 sheets with the same name
        ShtDest.Cells.PasteSpecial xlValues
    Next Sht
    WB.Close
    Filename = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It served the purpose. Thanks.

Comment: @mechee69 you're welcome, please mark as "Answer ", by clicking on the **V** next to my answer, the check mark will turn green

Comment: The resultant workbook changes the sheet names. Can you please edit code in such a way that new sheet names remain alike original sheet names.

Comment: @mechee69 see edited code, I've added a line for this. You should be aware you might get an error in case there will be an attempt to create a sheet with the same name of another sheet.