# combine multiple workbooks in one excel-workbook

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I want to combine the first sheet of multiple workbooks into one master workbook. The data is always structured in the same manner. In addition to this, I want an extra sheet in my master workbook where all the data is summarized (to add up all the numbers of each sheet,eg 1+1+1=3).

So far I started with this code. Yet, I have no idea how to summarize in VBA with different workbooks (that is why it not included in the code)

thanks in advance folks!

````
'Defining
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim directory As String
Dim myFiles As String
Dim targetwb As Workbook
Set targetwb = ThisWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

directory = "C:\Dokumente\"
myFiles = Dir(directory & "*.xlsx")

'Loop through all files in a folder until DIR cannot find anymore

Do While myFiles <> ""

'Open Workbooks one by one 'Do i really have to use the "set command"???
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=directory & myFiles)

'The actual action

'Countries:

'Brazil:

If wb.Name = "Brazil*" Then
Worksheets("Status Overview").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Brazil")
End If

'Kosovo:

If wb.Name = "Kosovo*" Then
Worksheets("Status Overview").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Kosovo")
End If

'United States:

If wb.Name = "United States*" Then
Worksheets("Status Overview").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("United States")
End If

Workbooks(myFiles).Close

myFiles = Dir

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine multiple Excel workbooks into a single workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455076/combine-multiple-excel-workbooks-into-a-single-workbook)

Comment: Hey thank you for the link! It helps a lot. Do you have another link in regards to summarizing data out of multiple workbooks into one master sheet?

Comment: Would help to include in your question a concrete example of the exact type of thing you need to do - the code you posted does something entirely different.

Comment: ..."add up all the numbers of each sheet" is too vague to offer any suggestions.  What *exactly* do you need to do?

Comment: Since all the sheets (from country departments of my company) are structured in the same way, a certain information (eg profit) is always in the same cell. In the Masterbook I want to collect the country information as sheets but I also want to create a mastersheet where I can find the total profit. I hope this is a bit more concrete.

Answer (score 1):

Run this in a Workbook with one sheet name Summary.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Summarize()

    Const FOLDER = "C:\Dokumente\"
    Const WS_NAME = "Status Overview"
   
    'Defining
    Dim wbIn As Workbook, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, ar, s
    Dim filename As String, msg As String
    Dim copied As Collection
    Set copied = New Collection

    ar = Array("Brazil", "Kosovo", "United States")
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    filename = Dir(FOLDER & "*.xlsx")
    Do While filename <> ""
        For Each s In ar
            If LCase(filename) Like LCase(s) & "*" Then
                Set wbIn = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER & filename, True, True) ' update links, read only
                wbIn.Sheets(WS_NAME).Copy after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
                wbIn.Close False
                wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count).Name = s
                copied.Add s
                msg = msg & vbCrLf & s
            End If
        Next
        filename = Dir
    Loop

    ' build =SUM() formula
    Dim f As String, sep As String, rng As Range
   
    f = "=SUM("
    For Each s In copied
        f = f & sep & "'" & s & "'!RC"
        sep = ","
    Next
    f = f & ")"

   ' range to summate on summary sheet
    Set rng = wb.Sheets("Summary").Range("A10:E20")

    ' apply sum formula to range
    rng.FormulaR1C1 = f
   
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Imported :" & msg, vbInformation

End Sub
```